# Laravel : The best way to transform a belongsTo logic to belongsToMany?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

My app is about artists painting walls.

At this point an artist has many walls and a wall belongs to an artist.

But now I want to make possible a Wall to belongsToMany Artists. (sometimes a wall is painted by 2 or more artists...)

I can't figure myself the best way to solve that. What about:

1 - a pivot table : artist_wall
where Wall belongsToMany Artists
and Artist hasMany Walls

> • is it possible? or must i have belongsToMany relationship on both side?
>
> • I have already 150+ wall records with artist_id field. Feels like a risky mission to transfer the relationship in the pivot table

2 - an array of artist_ids in my wall table

> • then i guess i will loose the benefit of the eloquent relationship
>
> • looks dirty

Any experience to share? is it clear enough?
I'm using Laravel 5.

Thanks!

Comment: You are describing a many to many relationship.  Set this up in your database.

Comment: with belongsToMany on both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a many to many relationship. You should have 3 tables:

- Artists (ID, Description, ...)
- Artists_Walls (ArtistID, WallID, ...)
- Walls (ID , Description, ...)

Then you can use joins to get for example all the walls for an artist like this:

```
select * from Artists a
inner join Artists_Walls aw on a.ID = aw.ArtistID
where a.ID = '1'
```

If you want the opposite then you do the contrary by joinning `Walls` on `Artists_Walls`

Comment: Thanks. I was on that solution but i was confused by using artist belongsToMany Walls. For me it would have made more sense keeping : artist hasMany walls. But many to many relationship works like that. And to retrieve all the walls with Laravel, its even easier: artist->walls->get(). And I just used php artisan seeder to seed my pivot table. cool.